# Scraping dynamic pages with node.js and headless browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, headless-browser

I'm trying to scrap data from the page that is loading dynamically. For this I'm using headless browser *puppeteer*

> **Puppeteer** can be seen as the *headlessBrowserClient* in the code.

The main challenge is to gracefully close the browser as soon as needed data received. But if you close it earlier than evaluateCustomCode execution is finished - evaluateCustomCode progress would be lost.

> **evaluateCustomCode** is a function that can be called as if we run it in the Chrome Dev tools.

To have control over the network requests and async flow of puppeteer API - I use async generator that encapsulates all the logic described above.

**The problem is that I feel that the code smells, but I can't see any better solution.**

Ideas ?

```js
module.exports = function buildClient (headlessBrowserClient) {
  const getPageContent = async (pageUrl, evaluateCustomCode) => {
    const request = sendRequest(pageUrl)
    const { value: page } = await request.next()

    if (page) {
      const pageContent = await page.evaluate(evaluateCustomCode)
      request.next()

      return pageContent
    }
  }

  async function * sendRequest (url) {
    const browser = await headlessBrowserClient.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    const state = {
      req: { url },
    }

    try {
      await page.goto(url)
      yield page
    } catch (error) {
      throw new APIError(error, state)
    } finally {
      yield browser.close()
    }
  }

  return {
    getPageContent,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `waitForFunction` or `waitFor` and `evaluate` with `Promise.all`. No matter how dynamic the website is, you are waiting for something to be true at end and close the browser when that happens.

Since I do not have access to your dynamic url, I am going to use some random variables and delays as example. It will resolve once the variable returns truthy.

```
await page.waitForFunction((()=>!!someVariableThatShouldBeTrue);
```

If your dynamic page actually creates a selector somewhere after you evaluate the code? In that case,

```
await page.waitFor('someSelector')
```

Now back to your customCode, let me rename that for you a bit,

```
await page.evaluate(customCode)
```

Where customCode is something that will set a variable `someVariableThatShouldBeTrue` to true somewhere. Honestly it can be anything, a request, a string or anything. The possibilities are endless.

**You can put a promise inside page.evaluate**, recent chromium supports them very well. So the following will work too, resolve once you are loaded the function/data. Make sure the customCode is an async function or returns promise.

```
const pageContent = await page.evaluate(CustomCode);
```

Alright, now we have all required pieces. I modified the code a bit so it doesn't smell to me :D ,

```
module.exports = function buildClient(headlessBrowserClient) {
  return {
    getPageContent: async (url, CustomCode) => {
      const state = {
        req: { url },
      };
      // so that we can call them on "finally" block
      let browser, page;
      try {
        // launch browser
        browser = await headlessBrowserClient.launch()
        page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url)

        // evaluate and wait for something to happen
        // first element returns the pageContent, but whole will resolve if both ends truthy
        const [pageContent] = await Promise.all([
          await page.evaluate(CustomCode),
          await page.waitForFunction((() => !!someVariableThatShouldBeTrue))
        ])

        // Or, You realize you can put a promise inside page.evaluate, recent chromium supports them very well
        // const pageContent = await page.evaluate(CustomCode)

        return pageContent;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new APIError(error, state)
      } finally {
        // NOTE: Maybe we can move them on a different function
        await page.close()
        await browser.close()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can change and tweak it more as you wish. I did not test the final code (since I don't have APIError, evaluateCustomCode etc) but it should work.

It doesn't have all those generators and stuff like that. **Promises**, That's how you can deal with dynamic pages :D .

PS: IMO, Such questions are more befitting for [the code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).